# jQuery animate not working in touched event

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-events, touch-event

In following code the `$('#slidemenu-container').animate(...)` isn't working:

```
$(document).live('touchend', function(event, data) {
    var container = $("#slidemenu-container");
    var container2 = $("#bg-yellow-id");

    if (container.has(event.target).length === 0 && container2.has(event.target).length === 0 && settings.katMenuVisible) {

        // workaround because showHide(...) with animate isnt working
        var left = '-=' + settings.listSlideWidth + 'px';
        $("#show-hide-kat").css({
            'background-image': "url('" + yiiBaseUrl + "/images/NAVbutton_opennav.png')"
        });

        $('#slidemenu-container').animate({
            left: left,
        }, settings.duration, function() {

        });

        settings.katMenuVisible = !settings.katMenuVisible;

    }
});
```

It works if I modify the left property with the `.css()` function:

```
$(document).live('touchend', function(event, data) {
    var container = $("#slidemenu-container");
    var container2 = $("#bg-yellow-id");

    if (container.has(event.target).length === 0 && container2.has(event.target).length === 0 && settings.katMenuVisible) {

        // workaround because showHide(...) with animate isnt working
        var left = '-=' + settings.listSlideWidth + 'px';
        $("#show-hide-kat").css({
            'background-image': "url('" + yiiBaseUrl + "/images/NAVbutton_opennav.png')"
        });

        container.css({
            'left': left
        });

        settings.katMenuVisible = !settings.katMenuVisible;

    }
});
```

What's the problem? I tried everything, but animate is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps try something simpler like:
.animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");

Btw, I am not sure what your trying to do anyway, your trying to make it switch to left and animate? Make it appear?